# Input on datetime-local doesn't work if value is set via script

Tags: html, html-input

Suppose I have the following date/time input:

```
<input type="datetime-local" value="2020-07-08T01:40:01.123" />
```

This displays the date/time in a date/time picker.  Choosing a new date/time updates the value as expected.

Now, suppose I have an date/time input where I set its value with script:

```
<input type="datetime-local" />
```

Later in my JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('input').value = '2020-07-08T01:40:01.123';
```

This appears to result in the same date/time picker and value, just like the first example.  Except that the user isn't able to update the date/time.  It's seemingly locked to whatever it was originally set to.

Am I setting the value correctly?  Is this a browser bug?  I'm using Chrome on Windows.

JSFiddle Example:  https://jsfiddle.net/4buswncz/

Comment: You can do: `document.querySelector('input').setAttribute('value', '2020-07-08T01:40:01.123');`, as to why it's locking the UI, I'm not too sure...

Comment: Thanks Nick.  Yeah, that workaround may work.  Unfortunately, I'll have to modify my UI library (Riot.js) to do it, as it appears that it's using `.value` and not calling `setAttribute` for some reason.  Hmmm.  I'll dig into it.  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Your fiddle works for me in Chrome (the 2nd latest version :) ). I don't get the popup calendar in FF (latest version) whether its set via script or not, but it is still editable. What browser are you using?

Comment: @FluffyKitten Strange... I'm using Chrome v83.0.4103.116 on Windows, 64-bit.  For me, if I click the calendar icon to open the selector, and choose any of the other values, the value of the actual box doesn't update.

Comment: Sorry, you're right... I was using the arrows and number keys to edit the date and they both work fine. The calendar dates were selectable but I didn't think to check if they actually changed the date. Strange that it can be changed via the text field but not through the popup calendar...